# Expanding standard Polygon class

Tags: wpf, union, polygon

I am trying to create a program which can union polygons. I want to create a Polygon class, which can do some operations like Initialize, FindOfOrientation and so on. I am using WPF and with an abstract class - Shape. I want to inherit it and use some properties of this class. But I have problem with Property: "System.Windows.Media.Geometry DefiningGeometry" How should I accomplish this?

```
 class SpecialPolygon: Shape
{

    #region Constants
    private const int STROKE_THIKNESS = 1; // Толщина линии
    private const double OPACITY = 0.5;    // Прозрачность
    #endregion

    int _amountOfVertexes;                // Количество сторон полигона
    List<Point> _listOfVertexes;          // Список всех вершин
    List<Stroke> _listOfStrokes;         // Список ребер
    PointCollection Points { get; set; }
    protected override System.Windows.Media.Geometry DefiningGeometry

    {
       WHAT I SHOULD WRITE IN THIS CASE ???

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Конструктор с параметрами инициализирует полигон с заданным количеством вершин
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="amountOfVertexes">Число вершин</param>
    /// <param name="listOfVertexes">Список координат</param>
    public SpecialPolygon(int amountOfVertexes, List<Point> listOfVertexes)
    {
        _amountOfVertexes = amountOfVertexes;
        _listOfVertexes = listOfVertexes;
        _listOfStrokes = new List<Stroke>();

        this.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
        this.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightBlue;
        this.StrokeThickness = STROKE_THIKNESS;
        this.Opacity = OPACITY;
        this.Points = new PointCollection();

        for (int i = 0; i < _amountOfVertexes; i++)
        {
            Point a;
            a = _listOfVertexes[i];
            this.Points.Add(a);
        }
            // Записываем каждую пару точек в отрезок.(Точка начала отрезка и конца)
        for (int i = 0; i < _amountOfVertexes - 1; i++)
            {
                Stroke stroke = new Stroke(_listOfVertexes[i], _listOfVertexes[i + 1]);
                this._listOfStrokes.Add(stroke);
            }
  // Не забываем записать последний отрезок, соединяющий конец ломанной с её началом
  // Таким образом получается полигон
        Stroke lastStroke = new Stroke(_listOfVertexes[_amountOfVertexes - 1], _listOfVertexes[0]);         
        this._listOfStrokes.Add(lastStroke);
    }
```

Comment: The `DefiningGeometry` property would simply return the Geometry that makes up your Shape. It could be a PathGeometry or StreamGeometry that contains the Points from your `Points` property. The `_listOfStrokes` thing is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than going over subject matter in detail that has already been written many times before, I'll just give you a summary and a link to a book that has an excellent section that will answer all of your questions and probably a few that you didn't even have. As @Clemens succinctly said, *The DefiningGeometry property would simply return the Geometry that makes up your Shape*.

The following example of how to create a `Geometry` object was taken from the excellent [*WPF Control Development Unleashed*](http://www.adorkable.us/books/wpf_control_development.pdf) book:

```
private Geometry GetArcGeometry()
{
    Point startPoint = PointAtAngle(Math.Min(StartAngle, EndAngle));
    Point endPoint = PointAtAngle(Math.Max(StartAngle, EndAngle));
    Size arcSize = new Size(Math.Max(0, (RenderSize.Width –
    StrokeThickness)/2),
    Math.Max(0, (RenderSize.Height - StrokeThickness)/2));
    bool isLargeArc = Math.Abs(EndAngle - StartAngle) 180;
    StreamGeometry geom = new StreamGeometry();
    using (StreamGeometryContext context = geom.Open())
    {
        context.BeginFigure(startPoint, false, false);
        context.ArcTo(endPoint, arcSize, 0, isLargeArc,
        SweepDirection.Counterclockwise, true, false);
    }
    geom.Transform = new TranslateTransform(StrokeThickness/2,
    StrokeThickness/2);
    return geom;
}
```

I'd recommend that you read the *Sample: Building a Circular Minute Timer* section, starting on page 40, but really, you could do a lot worse than read the whole thing. While I'm suggesting reading material for you, it seems that it might be a good idea for you to read through the various pages of the StackOverflow [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)... it will help you to get the most out of this website.